# Locally ringed point space is not a scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, ringed-spaces

Let $X$ be the point space $\{*\}$, and let the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ be given by:
$$\mathcal{O}_X (X) = \mathcal{O}_X (\{*\}) := \mathbb{Z}_p$$
$$\mathcal{O}_X (\varnothing) := 0$$
Why is it the case that $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is only a locally ringed space and not a scheme ?

Comment: Every point in a scheme should have an open neighborhood which is isomorphic to an affine scheme. When you apply that definition here, what goes wrong?

Comment: @KReiser Is it because $Spec \mathbb{Z}_p$ is not just 1 point ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. You should answer your own question!